# Font bolder in my Firefox, but not in friend's

Tags: fonts, bold, html-rendering

Corbel font looks as it should in all browsers except Firefox !on my pc! (i have all browsers updated), but friend of mine sent me a screenshot from all his browsers and he doesnt have this issue.

```
nav li a {
text-decoration:none;
font-family:"Corbel";
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
padding-right:40px;
padding-top:19px;
padding-bottom:5px;
padding-left:10px;
margin-bottom:20px;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;  /* FF4+ */
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;/* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;  /* IE10? */
transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

I know all browsers render fonts differently, but its weird his browsers render it same

Comment: so actually it looks same on my laptop, problem is just on my desktop, any idea why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

Is there **any** chance you have changed settings in your Firefox? I personally customize the fonts used and always change to a non-serif default variable-width font. Thus my own personal FF browser isn't a "reference" for testing.

For browser testing, can you make another profile and use a completely standard FF profile for browser testing? I refer to Mozilla's how to manage profiles page often: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles

Comment: I didnt change anything, I even tried to start Firefox in safe mode and reset all settings.

Comment: The thing is, unless it is a completely fresh install, I'm not sure I would trust that it hasn't been tainted. Perhaps create a new user in your OS (I'm assuming windows?) and then do a fresh instance/install of FF for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Try:
font-family:Corbel;

without the "

I'm totally guessing though as i don't see any glaring issue in that code snippet.